# Running nunit-console.exe fails while GUI is also running

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I'm trying to run nunit-console.exe from a script and I get an 'Unable to locate fixture' error, but only when I have NUnit GUI also running.  Once I close the NUnit GUI the script runs the tests just fine.

Here is nunit command being executed by the script;

```
"C:\Dev\Test1\Build\NUnit\nunit-console.exe" "C:\Dev\Test1\Tests\bin\Release\Test1.Tests.dll" /framework=v4.0.30319
```

It can even be a different version of the NUnit GUI that is running and it still interferes (ver 2.5.1 vs 2.5.5).  It think it has something to do with the nunit-agent.exe as it runs (spawned by the nunit-console.exe process) when the GUI is not running, but it doesn't run when the nunit colsole runs while the GUI is also running.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to run both at the same time?

Comment: It is just my development habit.  While developing I run NUnit GUI so every time I compile the tests are run.  Then when I want to commit a new version to source control I run the build script, which increments the build number, packages the files, and does other stuff like running tests in a console.  This will fail if I also have the GUI running.

Comment: Woo hoo! I got myself a Tumbleweed award!

Answer (score 1):

I found this same problem too, which appeared unexpectedly.

The only information that I had found online about it, was a question that someone had  [posted in a forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nunit-discuss/dFeNT_ETkek%5B1-25%5D) and that Charlie Poole (one of the NUnit authors) had responded to it.

Basically, the bug was found in 2.5.5 and was fixed in the next release, available from the [NUnit.org download](http://nunit.org/?p=download)  page of the website.

For me, this meant upgrading to NUnit 2.6.1 and the problem disappeared.

I hope this helps to clear your tumbleweed away! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nunit-console-x86.exe` instead of `nunit-console.exe`.

Also, try using `/framework=4.0` instead of `/framework=v4.0.30319`.

Lastly, I've had similar issues when I try to run `nunit-console-x86.exe` using a different user account than the logged in user, and so I resolved this by running the exe using the same user account.

Maybe this question will also help: [nunit-console can not loacte fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526678/nunit-console-can-not-loacte-fixture)

Also see this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/582051

Good luck! :)